# Masked values in numpy digitize

Tags: python, numpy, nan, masked-array

I want that `numpy digitize` ignores some values in my array. To achieve this I replaced the unwanted values by `NaN` and masked the `NaN` values:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.ma.array(A, mask=np.isnan(A))
```

Nonetheless `np.digitize`  throws the masked values out as `-1`. Is there an alternative way so that `np.digitize` ignores the masked values (or `NaN`)?

Comment: is it a 1D array?

Comment: @some_name.py yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope its not meant to be a performance optimization otherwise you can just 
mask after the digitize function:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(10,dtype=np.float)
A[0] = np.nan
A[-1] = np.nan

bins = np.array([1,2,7])

res = np.digitize(A,bins)

# here np.nan is assigned to the highes bin 
# using numpy '1.17.2'
print(res)

# sp you mask you array after the execution of 
# np.digitize
print(res[~np.isnan(A)])
```

```py
>>> [3 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3]
>>> [1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3]
```